# What does best block time mean in wallet.dat

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, block, wallet.dat, timestamp

I have a wallet.dat file that states:

- Best block at time of backup was 42603 (0000000013136bd812212959a15ef0ea0f084ee2c64e2f7f0e127d198f67a37f),
  mined on 2010-02-26T00:36:08Z

Does that mean that one of my address mined on that block?  Or is it just referenced with no correlation to my private keys with unspent coins?

Comment: may I ask how did you open and saw thr contents of wallet.dat?

Comment: I did dumpwallet on bitcoin core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the time the wallet was last synchronized to, it won't know about any transaction changes in or out past this time until it has been loaded again by a synchronized node. It has nothing to do with your transactions specifically.

Comment: may I ask how can someone open and see the contents of wallet.dat?

Comment: You can’t really. It’s a berkeleydb database without a lot of human readable structure, it’s only meant to be read by machine.

Comment: But the original poster hinted he could see the contents: "I have a wallet.dat file that states..."

Comment: So even if I add these private keys to another wallet, the balance wont show because i never did full node with bitcoin core?  Because I've checked over 1000 addresses so far and 0.00 :(     I believe that this wallet.dat came from my Guiminer I had on my computer I downloaded in 2011.